# VBA code using XMLHttpRequest always returns #VALUE! in Excel

Tags: ajax, vba, excel, bing-api

I'm trying to get the address in

https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/40.6718266667,-73.7601944444?o=xml&key=AqF-lvBxcTAEbhY5v0MfOHxhplD5NyaznesQ1IA5KS_RNghU1zrDiYN704mlrc8A

That's the ("//Location/Name")

The code is :

```
Function FindALocationByPoint(Lat As String, Lon As String, BingMapsKey As String) As String
Dim myRequest As XMLHTTP60

Dim uu As String
uu = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/" & Lat & "," & Lon & "?o=xml&key=" & BingMapsKey

Set myRequest = New XMLHTTP60
myRequest.Open "POST", uu, 0

myRequest.send

FindALocationByPoint = myRequest.readyState
```

(I know the final line should be `FindALocationByPoint = myRequest.responseXML.SelectNodes("//Location/Name").Item(0).Text`) That will also return `#VALUE!` I think the main problem is the unsuccessful connection to the website.

Then the cell`=FindALocationByPoint(K2,L2,$W$4)`will return`#VALUE!`
If I delete `myRequest.send` then the cell will return 1, which means server connection established, right?

Then, why adding `myRequest.send` will return `#VALUE!` ?

Any Guidance?

THANK YOU SO MUCH. I've working with this for two days.
If I change the URL and set `uu` equals another Geocoding website, there is no problem.
So is there something wrong with the website?(Microsoft Bing)
But I must use Bing, how to deal with this?

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you using post?

Comment: Try debugging this by calling it from another Sub. Calling it from the worksheet if there's a problem it will not break on the error: it will just keep returning #VALUE

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is not the problem here. You can load and use the long path to access:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Const URL As String = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/40.6718266667,-73.7601944444?o=xml&key=AqF-lvBxcTAEbhY5v0MfOHxhplD5NyaznesQ1IA5KS_RNghU1zrDiYN704mlrc8A"
    Dim sResponse As String, xmlDoc As Object    'MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        sResponse = .responseText
    End With

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument") 'New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    With xmlDoc
        .validateOnParse = True
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .async = False

        If Not .LoadXML(sResponse) Then
            Err.Raise .parseError.ErrorCode, , .parseError.reason
        End If

        Dim a As IXMLDOMElement
        Set a = .LastChild.LastChild.FirstChild.LastChild.FirstChild.FirstChild

        Debug.Print a.nodeTypedValue
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the following script, it wll print you the same addresse twice dug out from different nodes. Let me know if this is what you expected or I got you wrong.

```
Sub GetAddress()
    Const URL$ = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/40.6718266667,-73.7601944444?o=xml&key=AqF-lvBxcTAEbhY5v0MfOHxhplD5NyaznesQ1IA5KS_RNghU1zrDiYN704mlrc8A"
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, elem$, elemAno$

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
        xmlDoc.LoadXML .responseXML.XML
    End With

    elem = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Location/Name")(0).Text
    elemAno = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Address/FormattedAddress")(0).Text

    Debug.Print elem, elemAno
End Sub
```