# Alternative to WEBSERVICE formula (VBA function)

Tags: excel, xml, vba, web-scraping

I am using WEBSERVICE function on my worksheet to get data from XML file. Is there any alternative to this as corporation policy is blocking WEBSERVICE formula by default and it has to be enabled manually each time I open my Workbook (Enable Content).

I am currently using WEBSERVICE to receive distance and traveling hours from Google Maps.

Output from Google Maps XML:

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<origin_address>London, UK</origin_address>
<destination_address>Manchester, UK</destination_address>
<row>
<element>
<status>OK</status>
<duration>
<value>14735</value>
<text>4 hours 6 mins</text>
</duration>
<distance>
<value>335534</value>
<text>336 km</text>
</distance>
</element>
</row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

I would like to paste this output to Worksheet from where I can get the values and use them further.

Additionally I would like to get currency rates from ECB. 
https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

WEBSERVICE does not work for ECB XML at all for example beacuase it is blocked by corporation policy. So I was thinking will it help somehow if there would be alternative VBA function for this operation in Workbook.

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

With help from QHarr I got it working:

```
Sub XmlHttpTutorial()
Dim xmlhttp As Object
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
Dim myurl As String
myurl = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml" 'replace with your URL
xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
xmlhttp.Send
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = xmlhttp.responseText
End Sub
```

The only question left is how to paste it like in original XML file so it would look like in Excel table, starting from cell A1 (not whole XML in one cell):

```
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
<gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
<gesmes:Sender>
<gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
</gesmes:Sender>
<Cube>
<Cube time="2019-06-26">
<Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1362"/>
<Cube currency="JPY" rate="122.40"/>
<Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
<Cube currency="CZK" rate="25.486"/>
<Cube currency="DKK" rate="7.4651"/>
<Cube currency="GBP" rate="0.89603"/>
<Cube currency="HUF" rate="323.50"/>
<Cube currency="PLN" rate="4.2627"/>
<Cube currency="RON" rate="4.7220"/>
<Cube currency="SEK" rate="10.5435"/>
<Cube currency="CHF" rate="1.1113"/>
<Cube currency="ISK" rate="141.50"/>
<Cube currency="NOK" rate="9.6733"/>
<Cube currency="HRK" rate="7.3956"/>
<Cube currency="RUB" rate="71.6399"/>
<Cube currency="TRY" rate="6.5500"/>
<Cube currency="AUD" rate="1.6277"/>
<Cube currency="BRL" rate="4.3624"/>
<Cube currency="CAD" rate="1.4947"/>
<Cube currency="CNY" rate="7.8139"/>
<Cube currency="HKD" rate="8.8724"/>
<Cube currency="IDR" rate="16097.68"/>
<Cube currency="ILS" rate="4.0825"/>
<Cube currency="INR" rate="78.5705"/>
<Cube currency="KRW" rate="1312.86"/>
<Cube currency="MXN" rate="21.7972"/>
<Cube currency="MYR" rate="4.7124"/>
<Cube currency="NZD" rate="1.7004"/>
<Cube currency="PHP" rate="58.456"/>
<Cube currency="SGD" rate="1.5387"/>
<Cube currency="THB" rate="34.955"/>
<Cube currency="ZAR" rate="16.2802"/>
</Cube>
</Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

Comment: Did you try xmlhttp? https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/ If your policy allows you to run that then you can certainly get the currency rates. Google maps - you haven't provided an url so unsure.

Comment: I don't want to provide Google Maps link because there is an API key that can be used then by other people that is not good as it is not free and we are paying for it.

Comment: No worries. It looks like same applies as for my comment above (beginning thereof) Request with xmlhttp and parse with HTML parser or XML parser i.e. read response into xmlDocument or HTMLDocument. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51804477/6241235, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55999752/6241235

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I have edited my question. There is one issue left with solution provided.

Comment: One sec and I am writing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1) Using late bound html file

The following is deliberately set using late bound references given the restrictions you have noted.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetRates()
    Dim headers(), r As Long, html As Object, listings As Object, re As Object, p As String
    p = "time=""(.*?)"""
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    headers = Array("currency", "rate")
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set listings = html.getElementsByTagName("Cube")
    Dim results(), item As Long, dateVar As String
    ReDim results(1 To 50, 1 To 2)
    For item = 2 To listings.Length - 1
        r = r + 1
        results(r, 1) = listings(item).getAttribute("currency")
        results(r, 2) = listings(item).getAttribute("rate")
    Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With re
            .Global = True
            .Pattern = p
            dateVar = .Execute(listings(0).outerHTML)(0).SubMatches(0)
        End With
        .Cells(1, 1) = dateVar
        .Cells(3, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(4, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### 2) Using xml parser. Preference.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Const URL As String = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"
    Dim sResponse As String, xmlDoc As Object    'MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument") 'New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        sResponse = .responseText
    End With

    With xmlDoc
        .validateOnParse = True
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        .async = False

        If Not .LoadXML(sResponse) Then
            Err.Raise .parseError.ErrorCode, , .parseError.reason
        End If

        Dim dateVar As String, results(), rates As Object, rate As Object, r As Long
        dateVar = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//@time").Text
        Set rates = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//*[@currency]")
        ReDim results(1 To rates.Length, 1 To 2)
        For Each rate In rates
            r = r + 1
            results(r, 1) = rate.getAttribute("currency")
            results(r, 2) = rate.getAttribute("rate")
        Next
        Dim headers()
        headers = Array("currency", "rate")
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Cells(1, 1) = dateVar
            .Cells(3, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
            .Cells(4, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```